# Why does useState end up being undefined? with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Why does "console.log(data)" print undefined.
I've attempted to learn more about async javascript but I'm still confused

```
function updateData() {
       axios.get("http://localhost:8080/profile/get-status")
           .then((res) => {
               setData(res.data.data)
           });
       console.log(data);
   }
```

Comment: Also, you are calling `console.log(data);` before you send the request

Comment: mostly it's a standard async problem (logging before the request finishes), moving the `console.log` inside the `then` would illustrate the `useState` side of things as per the duplicate